# Lumen how to build serialised structure from models collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I have few tables in DB, with relations. For example:

```
user table
- id
- name
- email
- created_at

orders table
- id
- user_id
- status
- created_at

order_items table
- id
- order_id
- item_id
- count

items table
- id 
- article
- name
- ...
```

And finally I need transform data to this view -
Orders:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "status": "created",
    "user": {"id":1, "name":"Max"},
    "items":[{"id":1, "name":"Banana", "count": 2}, {...item two}]
  },
  {
    .. order two
  }
]
```

Some fields will be hidden (created_at, etc), and all models selected with it relations.

So, I can do something like

```
$userOrders = Orders::where([
    'user_id' => $request->user()->id
])
    ->select(['id'])
    ->with('orders.items') // <<<< oops nested relations
    ->get();
```

But problems:

1. How to select with nested relations
2. How to leave only needed fields from nested relations (ideally based on model scenarios when fields list depends on scenario)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to select anything, just use...

```
$userOrders = Orders::with('orders.items')->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->get();
```

And the things you want to hide will be set on each individual model.

For example, let's say on the user's attributes, you want to hide the `created_at` column.  Add the property...

```
protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];  // + any other fields you want to hide on the user model.
```

Comment: is it possible to set individual hidden "rules"? Let me explain, when selecting orders for /v1/orders I want return model without created_ attr, but when /v1/orderInfo I want return all model attributes..